# select width and height all img tag without id and class in particular div

Tags: jquery

How to change the height and width of images inside the div?

```
<div id="divid">
    <img width="100" height="200" src="site.com">
    <p>text</p>
    <img width="230" height="120" src="site.com">
    <h3>text</h3>
    <img width="50" height="20" src="site.com">
    <img width="70" height="40" src="site.com">
</div>
```

Comment: what u try so far?

Comment: Do you want to set some width/height to all image?

Comment: excuse me. i want change width and height with jquery.

Comment: Use `$("#divid img").attr({"width": "100", "height": "100"});`

Comment: i want resize image inside text. example 120% larger images.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the style property.
Example:

```html
<div id="divid">
    <img style="width:100px; height:200px;" src="site.com">
    <p>text</p>
    <img style="width:230px; height:120px;" src="site.com">
    <h3>text</h3>
    <img style="width:50px; height:20px;" src="site.com">
    <img style="width:70px; height:40px;" src="site.com">
</div>
```